# Transaction problem in MyISAM

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the problem. I have couple tables in MySQL MyISAM tables. And also i have several queries one depend on another. Something of this kind:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL PRYMARY KEY,
  money int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL
);
INSERT INTO users(name, money) VALUES('user1', 700);
INSERT INTO users(name, money) VALUES('user2', 200);
```

I need to transfer money from 1 user to anouther

```
<?php
$query1 = "UPDATE users SET money=money-50 WHERE name = 'user1'";
$query2 = "UPDATE users SET money=money+50 WHERE name = 'user2'";
```

The problem is if connection breaks between these two queries, the money just get lost, first user looses them, the other one doesn't get them. I could use InnoDB or BDB to start transaction, and rollback both queries on error in any of them, but still i have **this asignment** for MyISAM.
How this problem normally get solved?

Comment: Try `PRIMARY` instead of `PRYMARY`

Comment: It normally gets solved by using a backend that supports transactions. Period.

Comment: PRYMARY is not the point here :) And there is no way to use tables that support transactions.

Comment: +1 for good question , eager to know that is there is any mechanism to perform secure transaction in myisam

Comment: Well, it seems like there is nothing like transactions in MyISAM. So i came up with using a trigger instead. Not as universal as i wanted, but still gets the work done, that's enough for now.

Comment: @kos Are you sure that using a trigger is atomic (either **all** or **none**)?

Comment: The person who assigned this to you and told you to use MyISAM is plainly an irresponsible and uneducated person. You can get sued for a mistake such as this one. **Never, never, never, never, never, never** use MyISAM for storing financial data or money transfers. No matter who told you that you *should, must, can, ought to* - do not do it. If you still *have to* do it, make sure you have a backup plan for when MyISAM does what it does the best and the whole feature backfires and shoots you in the foot.

Answer (score 2):

MyISAM does not provide any mechanism for handling this internally. If you need atomicity, use an engine which does support transactions, such as the InnoDB engine. This is the usual and accepted solution to this kind of problem.

Another possibility would be to store transactions rather than totals.

```
CREATE TABLE users(name VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (name));
CREATE TABLE transactions(from_user VARCHAR(255), to_user VARCHAR(255), amount INT);
```

This means transactions are now a single query, but finding the current balance is more difficult.

The transaction:

```
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES('user1', 'user2', 50);
```

Finding the balance is harder:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM transactions WHERE to_user='user2') - (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM transactions WHERE from_user='user2')
```

Since the record can't be only half inserted, this resolves the issue. Note I didn't say this was a good idea. **Use a transactional database.**

Note: There is one more way to do this which is rather ugly but should still be atomic with MyISAM.

```
UPDATE users SET money=IF(name='user1',money-50, money+50) WHERE name='user1' OR name='user2';
```

Comment: "more dificult"? It will be slow as hell for every user who really uses the system!

Comment: I never said it is good, I was just pointing out is is possible.

Comment: Well, it's not that simple. Actually the queries in this "transaction" set are far more complex, just didn't want to bother you with long lists of queries. It's more like checking if page with a certain number (which is position in the menu list) exists then all pages after it get incremented and if all this got done i add a new page to the pointed position. Is there any more common way to settle this problem?

Comment: @DarkFalcon The idea is good, but after having stored the transaction info, how do we actually DO the transaction atomically and change the balance of both accounts?

Comment: You don't. You are no longer storing the balance, only the change to the balance.

Comment: @DarkFalcon, is the atomicity of a single update guaranteed? (per your last example)

Comment: "The other nontransactional storage engines in MySQL Server (such as MyISAM) follow a different paradigm for data integrity called “atomic operations.” In transactional terms, MyISAM tables effectively always operate in autocommit = 1 mode." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, as several people have mentioned this isn't a good idea, and you shouldn't do this in any real system.  But I assume this is a homework assignment, and the goal is to figure out how to fake atomic updates in a system that doesn't support it.

You can do it by basically creating your own transaction log system.  The ideas is to create a set of [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) operations, i.e., operations you can repeat again if they get interrupted, and get the correct result.  Addition and subtraction are not idempotent, because if you add or subtract multiple times, you'll end up with a different result.  Assignment is.  So you can do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    committed boolean default false,
    user1 varchar(255), 
    user2 varchar(255),
    balance1 int,
    balance2 int,
    index (id, committed)
);
```

Then your "transaction" looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO transactions(user1, user2, balance1, balance2) 
    VALUES(
        'user1', 
        'user2', 
        (SELECT money + 50 FROM users where name='user1'),
        (SELECT money - 50 FROM users where name='user2')
    );
```

You then have a separate system or function that commits transactions.  Find the first uncommitted transaction, update both the accounts with the stored values, and mark the transaction as committed.  If the process gets interrupted, you'll be able to recover because you can play back transactions and  there will be no harm done if you play back a transaction more than once.

Comment: Can you elaborate exactly how do we do the 4 steps **atomically** ?: **1)** find the first uncommitted transaction **2)** update first account **3)** update second account **4)** mark the transaction as commited.

Comment: @Pacerier stored procedure maybe?

Comment: @DmitryScriptin But unless the table supports transactions internally, stored procs aren't atomic as well right

Comment: @Pacerier That's true. I meant if we can use proc to somehow emulate transactions - e.g., if we have procesures to emulate commit and rollback operations together with transactions table.

Comment: @DmitryScriptin Yes, but the real question is how do we actually do those things atomically with a non-transactional table?

Answer (score -4):

```
UPDATE users u1
INNER JOIN users u2
SET u1.money=u1.money-50, u2.money=u2.money+50
WHERE u1.name = 'user1'
AND u2.name = 'user2'
```

Comment: Statements which update multiple rows are not atomic in MyISAM. This will still fail in some cases.